# Upload and read/write files in meteor

Tags: meteor, fs, collectionfs

I'm trying to upload and read a file on the fly in meteor. However I didn't find any packages/tutorials to do this so I tried to use the FS library but I have some troubles with it.

I have a  in my template, and an event like this :

```
"change .myFileUpload": function(e, tmpl) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var fileInput = tmpl.find('input[type=file]');

    console.log('test');
    // grab a list of the files selected with the file chooser
    // input
    debugger;
    console.log(fileInput);
    var theFile = new FS.File(fileInput);
    console.log(theFile);
    var rose = JSON.parse(Assets.getText(fileInput));
    Meteor.call('readTxtFile',fileInput);
    Meteor.call('readTxtFile',theFile);
}
```

The method readTxtFile looks like this :

```
    readTxtFile : function(file){
    console.log(file);
    fs.readFile(file, function(err,data){
        if(err){
            throw new Error("Fail read");
        }else{
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

But, when I upload a file, the page is reloaded with the file passed through arguments, the url looks like this : http://localhost:3000/port?myFileUpload=textfile.txt

The page is reloaded when the code execute the line http://localhost:3000/port?myFileUpload=textfile.txt

Even if I set a FS.debug = true; I can't see any error, neither through the client nor the server log; except the first log

```
console.log(fileInput);
> <input type=​"file" class=​"myFileUpload">​          portTmpl.js:12
```

Any thoughts ?

Comment: most people use the collectionfs package: https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS

Comment: If you're think CollectionFS is too complex, then try this one: https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-Files/

Comment: I can use the collection FS package but I don't see any method to read a file uploaded. And I don't get why I should use a collection since I just want to write and read files ?

Answer (score 0):

You need the following to prevent the window from handling the drop event with the default event:

```
window.addEventListener("drop",function(ev){
  ev = ev || event;
  ev.preventDefault();
},false);
```